# Sockets And Winapi32

Tags: c, winapi, sockets

I will want to learn some win32 api and sockets in C.

If someone can give me a beginner site to learn from I will thanked him very much..
thanks

Comment: What do you want to learn? WinAPI? or Socket programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN is great: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a great source for this.

Frostbytes.com [great tutorial on socket programming](http://www.frostbytes.com/~jimf/papers/sockets/sockets.html).

Boost.Asio also a great library [provided examples in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) !

Comment: beej's is for *Nix operation systems and I looking for windows platform.
Frostbytes dont work..

Comment: It has some notes on Windows differences. For the most part it is all the same using BSD sockets. Check the MSDN site for API differences.